# Is RepeatVector layer the same as Concatenate layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here was my code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, RepeatVector

Model = Sequential([
              LSTM(2, input_shape=(3,2)),
              RepeatVector(5)])

inputs = [[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]]
print(Model.predict(inputs))
```

which produces the output:

```
[[[0.03203796 0.00486411]
[0.03203796 0.00486411]
[0.03203796 0.00486411]
[0.03203796 0.00486411]
[0.03203796 0.00486411]]]
```

Now, it seems that adding Repeat Vector just repeated the same output `n` times. If RepeatVector just repeats the output `n` times, does this mean that `RepeatVector(n)` is the same as Concatenating the output to itself `n` times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs of [`RepeatVector`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RepeatVector) and [`concatenate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate), one of the differences is the output shape.

For `RepeatVector`, the output shape is: `(num_samples, n, features)`

For `concatenate`, the output shape is: `(num_samples, features*n)` (if `axis=-1`)

Let's visualize that. Here's some dummy input:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.reshape(tf.range(1, 10), (3, 3))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])>
```

Let's repeat the vector:

```
tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(n=3)(x)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]],
       [[7, 8, 9],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [7, 8, 9]]])>
```

Let's concatenate:

```
tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, x, x])
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 9), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]])>
```

The other difference is of course, the conceptual difference between repeating and concatenating.

Repeating:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Concatenating:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two layers, `Concatenate` and `RepeaVector` are syntactic sugar over the tensorflow ops [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) and [`tf.repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat) respectively.

Those 2 ops are there to mimic the numpy operations [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

Those 2 ops are different:

- repeat will repeat each element of the Tensor n times
- concat will concat the tensor with itself

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.arange(3)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> tf.repeat(a,3)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(9,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])>
>>> tf.concat((a,)*3,axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(9,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])>
```

`tf.repeat` was introduced in [a feature request on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8246.)